# Выход из try-catch

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

Использую axios для отправки запросов во vue.js 2 в laravel 5.7. В `bootstrap.js` (точке, где подключаются основные библиотеки - axios, twitter bootstrap и др) я для axios регистрирую общее поведение при отправке, ответе и ошибке:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    console.log('Отправлен запрос...');
    return config;
}, (error) => {axios_error(error)});

axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    console.log('Получен ответ.');
    return response.data;
}, (error) => {axios_error(error)});

function axios_error(error) {
    console.log('Ошибка запроса axios');
    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

Далее ([как в документации](https://github.com/axios/axios#example)) использую следующую конструкцию, чтобы дождаться ответ на запрос, а уже после выполнять остальные инструкции.

```
async createPerson(person) {
    try {
        let response = await axios.post('/people', person);
        this.setPersonData(response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
},
```

Видно, что вся конструкция обёрнута в `try-catch`. Однако неожиданно оказывается, что если запрос завершается ошибкой (код 422, например), то `this.setPersonData(response);`, будет выполнено.

Почему? И как прервать выполнение при ошибке?

Мой вариант такой:

```
async createPerson(person) {
    let response = await axios.post('/people', person);
    if (response) {
        this.setPersonData(response);
    }
},
```

Comment: Запрос завершается *какой* ошибкой?

Comment: @andreymal - 422

Comment: С точки зрения джаваскрипта это не ошибка, потому что запрос успешно отправлен и ответ от сервера успешно получен, а с каким он кодом — джаваскрипту это уже неважно. Ошибку 422 вам следует обрабатывать вручную

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас синтаксис не правильный

```
(error) => {axios_error(error)}
```

По сути ничего не сделает, потому что функция сама ничего не вернет. То что вы вызвали `Promise.reject` еще ничего не значит

```
(error) => axios_error(error)
```

Так уже фунция ошибки вернет `axios` именно `reject`, что должно вызвать всплытие ошибки

Answer (score 2):

Просто передайте функцию. Ваша конструкция стрелочной функции не возвращает результат.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    console.log('Получен ответ.');
    return response.data;
}, axios_error);
```